# Fetch all the js included using cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cheerio

Fetch all the js included in a website using cheerio.
I am fetching this URL **https://www.anandtech.com/**, when I use the code in webpage console it fetch all the js included on the webpage.

```
$("script[src]").each(function(i, src) {
    console.log($(this).attr("src")); 
});
```

but unable to fetch all the js using cheerio. it only fetch only few urls.

Comment: try the one i suggested!

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: If some of the scripts are dynamically generated or dynamically loaded, then the only way to find them all is to actually run the page in a head-less browser like phantomjs.

Comment: @jfriend00 I get these scripts in HTML and also in browser console using jquery but unable to find using cheerio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you  go!

```
$("script").map((i,$el) => {
  if($(this).attr("src")){
    console.log($(this).attr("src"))
  }else{
    let text = $($el).text()
    console.log(text)
  }
})
```